# Possible spam page pointing cloning or pointing to askubuntu.com, how can I report it?

Tags: support, spam-handling

I recently noticed on my google webmaster account that a link was pointing to my website - which I did not recognise, so I thought I would visit it (in an incognito window) to see what it was and it appears to be either some kind of phishing website or a clone of askubuntu.com.

I wasn't sure where I should report this, so I thought I would ask it as a question... how can I report this website? Below is the page in question, wrapped in code tags to avoid accidental clicking. Please visit with caution *and do **not** click the login button!*

`http://www.issuered.faith/`

Comment: That site is _full_ of ads. Wow

Comment: Holy cats, it looks so freakin real. The hot questions links are to the real SE sites xD

Comment: Do *not* click that "log in" button.

Comment: Yeah, I was very appalled when I saw it in my webmaster account!